# Getting the first word of a string and putting the remainder into another variable

Tags: php, string

Trying to set the first word of a string as a separate variable and taking the remainder and setting it as separate variable.

```
list($model, $submodel) = explode(' ', $full);
```

When I use list and explode I almost get the result I want but instead of the remainder of the string I get the 2nd word.

Comment: Is it possible your words can be delimited by something other than space (i.e. commas).   Keep that in mind as your design this.

Comment: @Sparky unfortunately not, I am trying to split up Model and Sub-Models of cars. Example: MDX Touring Package to Model: MDX Submodel: Touring Package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to split by the first space and therefore into 2 substrings, pass a limit of `2` to `explode()`, like so:

```
list($model, $submodel) = explode(' ', $full, 2);
```

Now `$model` will contain the first word and `$submodel` will contain the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

worst case scenario, you can manually get the first word using strpos() to get the space and substr to get the first word and str_replace to get it out of the rest of the string.
thats if all the good advices u get don't work.